# Nginx 404 error for react route deployed to subdirectory

Tags: nginx, hosting, web-hosting, nginx-config

I'm new in Nginx.

I built react project so that I can deploy it to a subdirectory.

It works well on local xampp server and All routes works fine.

> localhost/mysite.com/public
>
> localhost/mysite.com/public/signup
>
> localhost/mysite.com/public/admin

To host this site, I installed nginx on cloud computer(ubunbu 18.04).

I updated `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to set server configuration for this project.

my configuration is below

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mySite;
    root /var/www/html/mysite.com/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Once I try connect site (http://{ip address}/mysite.com/public), it loads first page.

But when I go to sub route, it returns "404 not found".

So I updated server config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mySite;
    root /var/www/html/mysite.com/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ /mysite.com/public {
        root /var/www/html/mysite.com/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

After update this configuration I can't restart nginx due to error.

I think it is because of wrong configuration.

But I can't know the reason due to little knowledge about nginx.

Comment: The `root` value appears to be wrong. The file path is the concatenation of the `root` value with the URI, so if you want a URI of `/mysite.com/public/foo` try `root /var/www/html;`. Not sure why you want the `/mysite.com/public` bit i the URI though?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with https://www.resonance.how/resonate-peace/resonate by doing this:

```
location /resonate-peace/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /resonate-peace/index.html =404;
}
```